# H264 in Firefox on Windows 7 N without Media Feature Pack?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, h.264, html5

How can I play H264 videos and MP3 audio in Firefox on Windows 7 N Professional without installing Windows Media Feature Pack? I know you can use GStreamer on Linux, but it doesn't work on Windows. I've installed `gstreamer-1.0-x86_64-1.4.1.msi` from [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.4.1/) with `Complete` setting, restarted Firefox and I still cannot play H264 videos.

Comment: Why can't you install the Windows Media Feature Pack?

Comment: I chose N version to have system without it. I don't want to install it. There has to be some other way to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, and directed at Windows 7 N, but this answer most likely will work on Windows 7 as well. Since I couldn't find the answer anywhere, I played around with Process Monitor (Sysinternals) to find the required files and registry keys. Tested successfully on Pale Moon 28.2.1 (x64) with H264 playback on Twitter and YouTube.

On Windows 10 N 64-bits, all you seem to need is the following (at least for H264 playback):

The file **mfperfhelper.dll** in your application folder (or Windows\System32 folder)
The file **msmpeg2vdec.dll** in your Windows\System32 folder
The file **mf.dll** in your Windows\System32 folder
The file **mfplat.dll** in your Windows\System32 folder
The file **evr.dll**  in your Windows\System32 folder

Extract these files from the Media Feature Pack installation file appropriate for your Windows version architecture (64-bits - amd64).

The following registry entries: (copy/paste to .reg file and import by double-clicking the file)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{62CE7E72-4C71-4D20-B15D-452831A87D9D}]
@="Microsoft H264 Video Decoder MFT"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{62CE7E72-4C71-4D20-B15D-452831A87D9D}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\msmpeg2vdec.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{e79167d7-1b85-4d78-b603-798e0e1a4c67}]
@="MF Media Source Activate"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{e79167d7-1b85-4d78-b603-798e0e1a4c67}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\mfcore.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
```

Comment: Based on the previous answer by Peter I've managed to pack everything and make it working for Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC N (1809 build). Just download the file, extract dlls. Then apply the reg patch. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsphseel0hnp38l/Codecs.zip?dl=1

Answer (score -1):

On Windows 10 N 64-bits (build 1809) it works, but blocks 'windows settings app'.
Even adding the missing file mfcore.dll.
Removing the registry key HKCR\CLSID{e79167d7-1b85-4d78-b603-798e0e1a4c67}
"MF Media Source Activate" 'windows settings app' returns to work.

Comment: I can confirm this. After removing key HKCR\CLSID{e79167d7-1b85-4d78-b603-798e0e1a4c67}  Settings app will work again but firefox playback stops working :(

Answer (score -2):

For Windows 7 SP1 N x64 it was enough to copy fallowing files:

- **mf.dll** in your Windows\System32 folder
- **mfplat.dll** in your Windows\System32 folder
- **evr.dll** in your Windows\System32 folder

Here are [extracted files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1avvxyiMw_jPgH64a2DepytlxwIPUAUNk)